# How to perform Arithmetic progression in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to count from number N1 until N2 with Increments of 100
For example

**46500 to 49999 Increments of 100**

```
Will print the following


46600
46700
46800
46900
47000
.
.
.
49900
```

Please advice how to implement (print) this counting with bash

Comment: Solution: `man seq`.

Comment: `seq` is the old school and an external command. There's builtins ;) See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `seq`

```
$ seq 46600 100 49999 
46600
46700
46800
46900
.
.
.
49600
49700
49800
49900
```

From man page

```
NAME
       seq - print a sequence of numbers

SYNOPSIS
       seq [OPTION]... LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
       seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

Comment: just one remark the first number shuld be 46600 , see my update quastion

Comment: @maihabunash to start the sequence at 46600 instead of 46500, I would guess you could change the command line from `seq 46500 ...` to `seq 46600 ...`. Just taking a stab in the dark of course...

Comment: other option is to use grep -v  ( for example seq $N1 100 $N2 | grep -v $N1

Comment: @maihabunash sorry i was away for sometime. The hack suggested by EdMorton would work fine though there can be many other ways as well

Answer (score 4):

### Using brace expansion, a new feature of  [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) only with builtins

(for the increment part) :

```
printf '%s\n' {46500..49999..100}
```

### Output

```
46500
46600
46700
46800
46900
47000
47100
47200
47300
(...)
49300
49400
49500
49600
49700
49800
49900
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use BASH's arithmetic evaluator `((...))` for this:

```
for ((i=46600; i<=49999; i+=100)); do echo $i; done
46500
46600
46700
...
...
49900
```

You can even use variable:

```
s=46600
e=49999
for ((i=$s; i<=$e; i+=100)); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: just one remark the first number shuld be 46600 , see my update quastion